# pytorch questions: how to add bias term and extract its value? class vs sequential model? and softmax

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I have a basic neural network model in pytorch like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
net = Net(400, 512,10)
```

How can I extract bias/intercept term from net.parameters()?
And is this model equivalent to using sequential()?

```
net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim[0]),
                      nn.Sigmoid(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_dim[0], hidden_dim[1]),
                      nn.Sigmoid(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_dim[1], output_dim))
```

Is nn.Softmax() optional at the end of either model for multi-class classification? If I understand correctly, with software it outputs probability of a certain class but without it returns predicted output?

Thanks in advance for answering my newbie questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer questions one by one. `is this model equivalent to using sequential()`
Short answer: No. You can see that you have added two Sigmoid and two linear layers. You can print your net and see the result:

```
net = Net(400, 512,10)

print(net.parameters())
print(net)
input_dim = 400
hidden_dim = 512
output_dim = 10

model = Net(400, 512,10)

net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim),
                      nn.Sigmoid(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
                      nn.Sigmoid(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim))

print(net)
```

The output is:

```
Net(
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=400, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (sigmoid): Sigmoid()
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
)

Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=400, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (1): Sigmoid()
  (2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (3): Sigmoid()
  (4): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

I hope you can see where they differ.

Your first question: `How can I extract bias/intercept term from net.parameters()`

The answer:

```
model = Net(400, 512,10)

bias = model.fc1.bias

print(bias)
```

the output is:

```
tensor([ 3.4078e-02,  3.1537e-02,  3.0819e-02,  2.6163e-03,  2.1002e-03,
         4.6842e-05, -1.6454e-02, -2.9456e-02,  2.0646e-02, -3.7626e-02,
         3.5531e-02,  4.7748e-02, -4.6566e-02, -1.3317e-02, -4.6593e-02,
        -8.9996e-03, -2.6568e-02, -2.8191e-02, -1.9806e-02,  4.9720e-02,
        ---------------------------------------------------------------
        -4.6214e-02, -3.2799e-02, -3.3605e-02, -4.9720e-02, -1.0293e-02,
         3.2559e-03, -6.6590e-03, -1.2456e-02, -4.4547e-02,  4.2101e-02,
        -2.4981e-02, -3.6840e-03], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I add another sigmoid in the class. does that make them the same? I mean if there is the same number of hidden nodes/layers and same activation function set up, functionally does nn.sequential() and class Net (nn.Module) do the same thing?

Comment: yes that's correct. If you add the same layers both in sequential and your custom-defined Net(nn.Module) class, then they have the same network architecture.

Answer (score 1):

you can you state_dict for extract  bias of each layer or function in Model.

the two present of your network is same but if you want do some extend of netwrok I will suggest use Net one instead of Sequential One

WithOut softmax it will just output a tensor witch  min -1 max 1 if use sigmoid , it can't be the predict.

AnyWay ,  you should answer your question seperate instead of one post for three question . good luck